# Combine two input post methods

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a simple question related to input post method. There are two input fields as follows :

```
$this->input->post('billed_date')
$this->input->post('branch_id')
```

Then I want to combine this two input post methods using logical "OR" argument. I used the following code :

```
if($this->input->post('billed_date', 'branch_id'))
{       
        .....some codes...
}
```

But didn't get the desired result. How can I combine these two post methods using "OR". Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `post()` method of CodeIgniter's input library doesn't support passing multiple keys in that way. You need to do it separately like this:

```
if ($this->input->post('billed_date') && $this->input->post('branch_id'))
{
    // ...your code here...
}
```

If you need it as logical OR (e.g only one variable needs to be present) you do it like this:

```
if ($this->input->post('billed_date') || $this->input->post('branch_id'))
{
    // ...your code here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for better understand using isset function within if condition

```
if (isset($this->input->post('billed_date')) || isset($this->input->post('branch_id')))
{
    // ...your code here...
}
```

or you may use OR replace on || then code like below

```
if (isset($this->input->post('billed_date')) OR isset($this->input->post('branch_id')))
{
    // ...your code here...
}
```